# unload inside iframe does not work on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to use the `.unload()` but I can't seem to make use of it. I have researched about this, and I saw that unload does not work when it is inside a iFrame for Google Chrome but for mozilla it works fine.

So my question is, is there anyway to use `unload` inside iFrame? I know using `load` as substitute would do it but it would spam the ajax every time the iFrame change's.

I've tried this code in Goggle Chrome and it does not work, but in Mozilla it works perfectly fine.

```
$(window).unload( function () { alert("Bye now!"); } );
```

any substitute for `unload` or anyway to use `unload`?

Comment: Have you ever tried using the beforeunload event?

Comment: what do you mean by before unload event?

Comment: It asks if you want to leave the page. Maybe this could be a raw solution. For example:
`window.onbeforeunload = function (){
    return "Bye now!"
}`

Comment: Or using jQuery:    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { return "Bye now!" });